# VBA copy data ignoring "" and header if no data exists

Tags: excel, vba

I have been working on a code that is supposed to copy information from input files to master file. All worked well until i tested files with no data.
Here is the problem:
Input file has 3 sections that user can fil in (expenses, mileage and allowance). Each of these inputs are collected in their own import sheet to prepare data for import later on. When i "collect" data in their own sheets i use formulas with iferror --> "", which means rows might not show values, but excel thinks that. 
Next step is to copy relevant data from each of the import sheets to master sheet. I want to always ignore header and i only want actual data and not "". 
I googled a formula that solved that "" issue to find last "used row" and was pretty happy :). However, if import sheet is empty, i.e not a single row apart from header is filled in, the magic stops working.. And the chances that a user only fills, say just expenses is very high.

Any of the bright minds have an idea how i address the issue? I really appreciate it!

```
Sub SPOTImport() 'SPOT import

   Dim Fname As Variant
   Dim SrcWbk As Workbook
   Dim DestWbk As Workbook
   Dim LastRow1 As Variant
   Dim LastRow2 As Variant
   Dim LastRow3 As Variant
   Dim LastRowHere As Variant
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim wbExport As Workbook
    Dim wsToExport As Worksheet
    Dim xPath As String
    xPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

    Set DestWbk = ThisWorkbook
    'delete all data but header to begin the preparation
LastRowHere = DestWbk.Sheets("Import").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
DestWbk.Sheets("Import").Range("A2:I" & LastRowHere).Delete

   'choose files and define them as array
   Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", Title:="Välj alla filer som lämnades in", MultiSelect:=True)
   If IsArray(Fname) Then
   'Define array start and finish
   For i = LBound(Fname) To UBound(Fname)

   'define workbook name based on each value in array
   Set SrcWbk = Workbooks.Open(Fname(i))

   'define lastrow for each sheeet that also ignores the "" in formulas
   LastRow1 = SrcWbk.Sheets("Import_EXPENSE").Columns("A").Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
   LastRow2 = SrcWbk.Sheets("Import_TRAVEL").Columns("A").Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
   LastRow3 = SrcWbk.Sheets("Import_ALLOWENCE").Columns("A").Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues).Row

      'copy data from each sheet to destnation file
     SrcWbk.Sheets("Import_EXPENSE").Range("A2:I" & LastRow1).Copy
    With DestWbk.Worksheets("Import").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With

      SrcWbk.Sheets("Import_TRAVEL").Range("A2:I" & LastRow2).Copy
    With DestWbk.Worksheets("Import").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With

     SrcWbk.Sheets("Import_ALLOWENCE").Range("A2:I21" & LastRow3).Copy
    With DestWbk.Worksheets("Import").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
SrcWbk.Close False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

   Next i
   End If

'export sheet as csv
Set wsToExport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import")     'Sheet to export as CSV
Set wbExport = Application.Workbooks.Add
wsToExport.Copy Before:=wbExport.Worksheets(wbExport.Worksheets.Count)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False                       'Possibly overwrite without asking
wbExport.SaveAs Filename:=xPath & "\" & "SPOT Import" & " " & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd"), FileFormat:=xlCSV
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
wbExport.Close SaveChanges:=False


'select sheet
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Import").Select

'magic ready
MsgBox "SPOT Import csv fil är klar!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Note that your row counting variables should all `Dim LastRow1 As Long`. Only use `Variant` if you have no other choice. It's the worst data type you could choose.

Comment: Thank you, @Peh, for the note. Will keep that in mind. Any ideas on the problem? i tried to remove headers from the import sheets, but then excel has completelly no idea what to do if there is no data, so that did not help :(

Answer (score 0):

Apply an Filter to your Source Sheet for "Value is not Blank" (e.g. `critieria:="<>"`) to filter out the Blank Rows, and use `WorksheetFunction.CountIf` to check if there *are* any non-blank rows in the sheet, before you do your copy.

Based on your code:

```
'Is there more data than just the Header Row in Column A?
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(SrcWbk.Sheets("Import_EXPENSE").Columns(1),"<>") > 1 Then
    'Filter for the data
    SrcWbk.Sheets("Import_EXPENSE").UsedRange.AutoFilter 1, "<>"
    'Copy the filtered data
    SrcWbk.Sheets("Import_EXPENSE").Range("A2:I" & LastRow1).Copy
    'Paste the data
    With DestWbk.Worksheets("Import").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
End If
```

There *are* other minor optimisations that can be done:  for example this code can be reduced by 2 stages:

```
'Long form, unoptimised
Range1.Copy
With Range2
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End With

'Remove the With
Range1.Copy
Range2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

'Direct copy, without using Clipboard
Range1.Copy Destination:=Range2
```

Comment: Thanx for suggestion!can you please help with a code example, vba is not my strengths as much as would like it to be..

Comment: @IrinaBan I have added some examples - hopefully they make sense!

Comment: thank you! what happens now is that it ignores all the "" rows, but copies header. I assume it is because header is last used row with data, but i am a bit confused as i am starting at row 2 here {SrcWbk.Sheets("Import_EXPENSE").Range("A2:I" & LastRow1).Copy}

Comment: does the problem lie in lastrow1 though? [LastRow1 = SrcWbk.Sheets("Import_EXPENSE").Columns("A").Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues).Row]

Comment: If `LastRow1` is 1, then it will be copying `Range("A2:I1")`, which is the same as `Range("A1:I2")`, and includes the Header row...  But, the `CountIf` *should* be meaning that you don't even try copying in that situation?

Comment: if i understood the question correctly - yes. pretty much if last row = 1, it does not need to copy anything as there is no data to be copied. How do i put this IF in there the smartest way?

Comment: i tried this, but then it takes blanks with it where data exists..   ´If LastRow1 > 1 Then
     SrcWbk.Sheets("Import_EXPENSE").Range("A2:I" & LastRow1).Copy
        With DestWbk.Worksheets("Import").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End With
      End If´

Comment: You need to include the `AutoFilter` line, and make sure that it is filtering on the correct column

Answer (score 0):

With help of lovely people out here i think i got it in the end. Here is the code, that ignores header and then sorts out blanks:

```
  If LastRow1 > 1 Then
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(SrcWbk.Sheets("Import_EXPENSE").Columns(1), "<>") > 1 Then 'Filter for the data
            SrcWbk.Sheets("Import_EXPENSE").UsedRange.AutoFilter 1, "<>" 'Copy the filtered data
            SrcWbk.Sheets("Import_EXPENSE").Range("A2:I" & LastRow1).Copy 'Paste the data
            With DestWbk.Worksheets("Import").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
            End If
      End If
```